# How to execute group by in another group by in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: `cars` and `lands`:

```
cars (id, land_id)
lands (id, district_id, location)
```

I need to get count of cars per each district. What I have now:

```
SELECT district_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM lands 
GROUP BY district_id
```

But of course it returns only count of lands per each district. How to get count of cars?

Expected result:

```
district_id | cars_count
1 | 30
3 | 10
...
```

Comment: You will need a join or a subquery, `select l.land_Id,count(c.id) from lands as l left join cars as c on l.land_id=c.Land_id group by l.land_id`

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you select only from **lands** table, when you also need to join **cars** table.

```
SELECT l.id, count(c.land_id)
FROM lands as l LEFT JOIN cars as c ON l.id = c.land_id
GROUP BY l.id
```

Comment: Hi, cars as cars  ? lands as lands ?

Comment: @VBoka Hi, oops, my bad

Comment: hey Danny! Unfortunately it does not work because I need to select how many cars I have per district, not per land

Comment: Hi @Alexxosipov what have you tried so far by yourself ? This answer  should be a big step forward in getting to your answer that now you can code yourself...

Comment: I've updated the question to make the expected result clear

Comment: @Alexxosipov so land_id in cars table is equal to district_id in lands table?

Comment: Not really. I've changed `l.id` to `l.district_id` and it works. Thank you!

Comment: @Alexxosipov that means that district_id is a foreign key. yw

Comment: not really. It is just an id of district which I have from 3rd party API. So there's no `districts` table

Answer (score 0):

left join these 2 tables based on land_id(cars) and id(lands)

```
select a.id,
       count(b.id) 
from lands a 
left join cars b on a.id=b.land_id 
group by 1;
```